# fusion free charts and arraylist

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

i am trying to use an arraylist to build a graph using fusionfree
however i cant get it to work, it keeps showing the same item from the array list

```
 Dim util As New Util()
    Dim region As New List(Of String)
    Dim int1 As New List(Of Integer)


    For Each rows As GridViewRow In GridView1.Rows
        ' Selects the text from the TextBox
        Dim regions As Label = CType(row.FindControl("label1"), Label)
        region.Add(Label1.Text)
        int1.Add(10)

    Next



    Dim strXML As String, i As Integer
    'Initialize <graph> element
    strXML = "<graph caption='Sales by Product' numberPrefix='$' formatNumberScale='0' decimalPrecision='0'>"

    'Convert data to XML and append
    Dim x As Int32
    x = 0
    For i = 0 To (region.Count) - 2
        x = (x + 1)
        'add values using <set name='...' value='...' color='...'/>
        strXML = strXML & "<set name='" & region.Item(x) & "' value='" & int1.Count & "' color='" & util.getFCColor() & "' />"
    Next
    'Close <graph> element
    strXML = strXML & "</graph>"

    'Create the chart - Column 3D Chart with data contained in strXML
    Return FusionCharts.RenderChart("../FusionCharts/FCF_Column3D.swf", "", strXML, "productSales", "600", "300", False, False)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In here, you are adding the same values over and over:

```
For Each rows As GridViewRow In GridView1.Rows
    ' Selects the text from the TextBox
    Dim regions As Label = CType(row.FindControl("label1"), Label)
    region.Add(Label1.Text) 'This should maybe be regions? You are always using Label1
    int1.Add(10)
Next
```

You are adding the `Text` property from Label1 (not the current row's `label1`) and 10 to region and int1 resp.

Also, is `row` declared somewhere above the loop above? I just noticed that your loop variable is `rows`, but you are trying to pull `label1` from `row`. Can you please clarify this discrepancy?

Comment: i got it to work i decided to loop through the datatable instead of the gridview makes more sense

Comment: my problem now is the program works on my computer but when i upload to server it doesnt

Comment: Line 170:        Return FusionCharts.RenderChart("../FusionCharts/FCF_Column3D.swf", "", strXML, "productSales", "1000", "500", False, False)

Comment: Compiler Error Message: BC30451: Name 'FusionCharts' is not declared.

Answer (score 1):

You could try http://liberofusioncharts.codeplex.com/. Make things simpler